# Question 2.3.5 Wayne Patty ( Closed sets in Product Topology)

Tags: general-topology

This question is from Foundations of topology by Wayne Patty(Pg 85).

> Let $X_n=\mathbb{R}$ for all n$\in \mathbb{N}$ and $T_n$ be lower limit topology on $X_n$ and T be the product topology on $X=\prod_{\mathbb{N}}X_n$. Prove that {x} , where $x_n$ =1 for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is closed subset of (X,T).

I am thinking by proving that complement of sequence is open and using the result that if $U_i$ is open for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_n $ is open in X.

complement of 1 is $(-\infty , 1) \bigcup (1, \infty)$ . but In lower limit topology $ (1,\infty)$ is not open.So, complement of 1 will not be open.

What mistake I am making ?

Can you please tell.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes.

- It is not in general true that $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ is open $X$ if each $U_n$ is open in $X_n$: this product set is open if and only if $\{n\in\Bbb N:U_n\ne X_n\}$ is finite.
- The complement of $\{1\}$ is indeed $(\leftarrow,1)\cup(1,\to)$, but the complement of $\{x\}$ is not $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$, where $U_n=(\leftarrow,1)\cup(1,\to)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.
- $(1,\to)$ **is** open in the lower limit topology: it’s the union of the sets $[x,\to)$ for $x>1$, and those sets are clearly open in the lower limit topology.

There are at least two reasonable ways to prove that $\{x\}$ is closed in the product topology. One is indeed to show that it’s complement is open, and you can use the sets $U_n=(\leftarrow,1)\cup(1,\to)$ to do it. HINT: For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$B_n=\prod_{k\in\Bbb N}V_k\,,$$

where

$$V_k=\begin{cases}
U_n,&\text{if }k=n\\
X_k,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

These sets $B_n$ are open in $X$. (Why?) Now show that $$X\setminus\{x\}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\,.$$

Another approach uses the following facts.

- The lower limit topology is $T_1$.
- The product of $T_1$ spaces is $T_1$.
- A space is $T_1$ if and only if every singleton (one-point subset) in it is closed.

(Of course if you’ve not yet proved these facts, you’d have to prove them in order to use them.)

Comment: Can you please explain why X\{x} = $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n$?

Comment: @Avenger: For each $n\in\Bbb N$ we clearly have $x\notin B_n$, since $x_n\notin U_n$; thus, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$. On the other hand, if $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, then there is at least one $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $y_n\ne 1$, so $y\in B_n$.

Answer (score 1):

We are told that $\{1\}$ is closed in the lower limit topology, so its complement is open; that one of the sets making up that union is not open does not imply that the union isn't open. (For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, the set $(0, 1)$ is open and can be written as $(0, 1) = (0, 1/2) \cup [1/2, 1)$, but $[1/2, 1)$ is not open).

One way to prove that $\{x\}$ is closed: the singleton set $\{1\}$ is compact in the lower limit topology; therefore $\{x\}$ is compact in the product topology by Tychonoff's theorem. So $\{x\}$ is closed (since the product topology of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff, compact sets are closed in this product space).

Comment: Sorry this comment is coming very late due to my chronic illness but can you help proving why {1} is compact in lower limit topology( 2nd para , 1st line ) of your answer?

Comment: A finite set is compact in any topology; this follows directly from the open cover definition of compactness.